# Loading iframe with content in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have made a textbox and an iframe in the same html. I want to load the 'html' rendered from textbox into html. I am using javascript button click event, but nothing is getting rendered. Pls help, I cant find where I am making mistake!

HTML:

```
<button onClick="convert()">Run</button> 

<textarea id="mycode">
    Hello World!
</textarea>

<iframe id="display"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
function convert()
{
   var x = document.getElementById('mycode').value;
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = x;
}
```

Can someone help, what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `src` of `iframe` to [`data URI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) representation of `textarea` value `x`

```js
function convert()
{
   var x = document.getElementById('mycode').value;
   document.getElementById('display').src = "data:text/plain," + x;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="convert()">Run</button> 

<textarea id="mycode">
    Hello World!
</textarea>

<iframe id="display"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = x;
```

with

```
document.getElementById('display').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't manipulate an iframe with Javascript (or jQuery) because the iframe is essentially a separate webpage. This is for security purposes, to prevent one website from embedding a malicious script into an iframe that can target the host page. There is no way around it, as far as I know. Generally it's not good practice to use iframes.

Answer (score 1):

I was browsing the answers for the same task. Well the accepted answer does help a little but the main task is to render "HTML". It works using the **[srcdoc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp)** attribute of the iframe tag.

```js
function convert()
{
   var x = document.getElementById('mycode').value;
   document.getElementById('display').srcdoc = x;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="convert()">Run</button> 

<textarea id="mycode">
    <!-- Comment is not rendered -->
    Hello World!
</textarea>

<iframe id="display"></iframe>
```